# Python Openpyxl: Copy and Paste from one Excel workbook to another - Content

Tags: python, openpyxl, excel-2019

This is my first time of using Openpyxl. So I am trying to copy and paste contents from one Excel workbook to another using the library. The code works fine when I execute it. However, my challenge is that instead of the code to copy the content below the the content already in the workbook, it replaces the content in the workbook. And this is not my objective.

I have tried to look at the tutorial and also do some research, but I could not seem to get what I was doing wrong. Below is the code that I am using

```
import openpyxl as opxl

#Opening the destination excel file
sourceFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\sourceFile.xlsx"

sourceworkbook = opxl.load_workbook(sourceFile)
sourceworksheet = sourceworkbook.worksheets[0]

#Opening the destination excel file
destinationFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\destinationFile.xlsx"

desinationworkbook = opxl.load_workbook(destinationFile)
destinationworksheet = desinationworkbook.active

# calculate total number of rows and 
# columns in source excel file
maximum_row = sourceworksheet.max_row
maximum_column = sourceworksheet.max_column

# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, maximum_row + 1):
    for j in range (1, maximum_column + 1):
        #reading the cell value from source excel file
        c = sourceworksheet.cell(row = i, column = j)
        
        #writing the value read from the source file to destination file
        destinationworksheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
        
#Save the destination excel file
sourceworkbook.save(str(destinationFile))

print("The File has been saved successfully")
```

I will appreciate it if someone can point me to what I am doing wrong or what I need to do.

Comment: This `destinationworksheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value` sets the writing to start from the first row. You can try with `row=i + destinationworksheet.max_row` so the writing can start from the max row for the sheet. Or you can use `ws.append()` that always appends the rows not rewrite them.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this and it changes nothing. It is still performing the overriding instead of appending

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to append content of excel1 to excel2. But problem is that you are overwriting it. Reason is that in excel2 you start to write from first row, instead of the last.

```
import openpyxl as opxl

#Opening the destination excel file
sourceFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\sourceFile.xlsx"

sourceworkbook = opxl.load_workbook(sourceFile)
sourceworksheet = sourceworkbook.worksheets[0]

#Opening the destination excel file
destinationFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\destinationFile.xlsx"

desinationworkbook = opxl.load_workbook(destinationFile)
destinationworksheet = desinationworkbook.active

# calculate total number of rows and 
# columns in source excel file
maximum_row = sourceworksheet.max_row
maximum_column = sourceworksheet.max_column

# find excel2 max_row
max_row_dest = destinationworksheet.max_row

# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, maximum_row + 1):
    for j in range (1, maximum_column + 1):
        #reading the cell value from source excel file
        c = sourceworksheet.cell(row = i, column = j)
        
        #writing the value read from the source file to destination file
        destinationworksheet.cell(row = max_row_dest, column = j).value = c.value
        max_row += 1
        
#Save the destination excel file
sourceworkbook.save(str(destinationFile))

print("The File has been saved successfully")
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried this and it changes nothing. It is still performing the overriding instead of appending

Answer (score 0):

The solution I am about to give might be 0.02 seconds slower but is a lot easier:

Use Pandas, An Intuitive python library:

```
import pandas as pd


sourceFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\sourceFile.xlsx"
destinationFile = "C:\\ForTesting\\destinationFile.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(sourceFile)
df.to_excel(destinationFile)
```